# unable to open ngrok tcp 8686

Tags: authentication, portforwarding, ngrok

when I run the command "./NGROK TCP 8686"
[I got this error as shown in the image--->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwlPS.png)

then I search for this on STACKOVERFLOW and then I used the command as suggested "./NGROK diagnose" [then I got this output as shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kubnb.png)

network type: bridged network

I was expecting to get an IP address and a port so that I can do port forwarding.